# How to get all results from yahoo local search

Tags: local, yahoo, web-crawler

I want to search all pizza in the region(zipcod=89030), then I construct a query in yahoo local search as:
http://local.yahooapis.com/LocalSearchService/V3/localSearch?appid=appid&query=pizza&zip=89030&results=20&start=250

The results xml file shows that there are
totalResultsAvailable="1714" totalResultsReturned="20" firstResultPosition="250"

The maximum number can be used in a url is 'results=20', 'start=250'. So I can only get maximum 250+20=270 results. But there are 1714 available results.

How can I get the remaining result tuples?

Requirement parameters can be found at: http://developer.yahoo.com/search/local/V3/localSearch.html

Answer (score 0):

Adding 'longitude' + 'latitude' + 'radius' to the url helps reduce the number of matched records to 270.

Is it the only solution?